# Array has Items, but can' find length

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get the length of an array which has objects in. I am using the following test method to loop through the array using the length. But for some reason the length is 0, even though it has 47 Items in it, see screenshot.

Code -

```
public test() {
    console.log(this._metadataModel.Currency);
    for (var i = 0; i <= this._metadataModel.Currency.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

The array

[image: Screen of console.log(array)]

From console I get--

[image: Empty array, yet has items]

Comment: How is that array generated?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you have an off-by-one error. You should loop until `i < array.length`, not `<=`

Comment: `console.log(this._metadataModel.Currency.length);` whats the result

Comment: I have added the result as a screenshot.

Comment: Note the console's view of an object (and array) are updated when you expand them in the console. So what you see was a view of it at that time, and not a view of it at the time of the call. Do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this._metadataModel.Currency))` to see exactly what the array is at the time of the for loop

Comment: I think the array is populated dynamically from a back-end service and then parsed into my Angular2+ UI

Comment: When you post screenshots, please give context. The second screenshot just shows an empty array, but it's not clear how you obtained that output.

Comment: My first guess is the array is populated asynchronously, and since the console is live, it will update. However at the time of the for loop, the Array is still empty.

Comment: @Darian the bottom line is you need to wait for the array to populate before using its data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: I delete my answer make sure that you have an array not a json object

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to log the contents of the array, before your load completed - aka "load meta data completed" is logged after your for. Try to make sure you're running the test method, once your data has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( var item of this._metadataModel.Currency ) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

Try this.

Then from `item` you can access `item.id`, `item.value`, etc.

Comment: This is not the issue; the problem is that the array is indeed empty when the `for` loop runs.

Comment: @ChrisG I see. My bad. But I guess this method eliminates the purpose of getting the length and be able to iterate the object. Unless he got something he wants to do with the index.